# TestNG annotations, method name same as parent class methods

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, annotations, testng

I started working with testNG, and found a little confusing behaviour.
i created a base class added few methods for each testNG notations then in the derived class did the same(method name different).. and run the derived class so before @test of derived class parent methods   running first and derived class methods running after that i.e before annotations and after@test of child the @after annotations ran vice versa.. up to here its clear.
Now , what i did  was changed the name of methods in derived class same as that of parent class now when i run the child/derived class only the child class methods run .

I am not able to understand why, no such thing is discussed anywhere!!

Answer (score 0):

In java  all methods are virtual. You derived class methods simply overrids base class methods.